# ¿Como imprimir varias paginas con printDocument en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando con Windows Forms, y no he logrado poder imprimir varias paginas con su respectivo pie y numeración haciendo uso de printDocument. 
Obtengo como resultado una sola impresión con todos los números superpuestos uno sobre otro.

Les comparto lo que tengo:

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
            PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings = ps;
            printDocument1.PrintPage += Imprimir;
            printDocument1.Print();
        }

private void Imprimir(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int num;
            string formulario1;
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            formulario1 = "N: ";

            for(num = 1; num < 15; num++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(formulario1 + num, font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(10, 10, 120, 20));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hola. Creo que la solucion tiene que ver con la propriedad `PrintPageEventArgs.HasMorePages`. Puede encontrar mas explicacion en el documentacion de Microsoft: [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-print-a-multi-page-text-file-in-windows-forms?view=netframework-4.8) y [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score -1):

En mi caso utilizo una función javascript, en esta se imprime todo lo que este incluido dentro de una etiqueta div

JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function ImprimirMovimiento(ImprimirMovimiento)
    {
        var ficha = document.getElementById(ImprimirMovimiento);
        var ventimp = window.open(' ', 'ImprimirMovimiento');
        ventimp.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()"><h1>Detalle movimiento cuenta de ahorros</h1><hr/>' + ficha.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
        ventimp.document.close();
        ventimp.print();
        ventimp.close();
    }
```

Aquí lo que se desee que se imprima:

```
<div id="ImprimirMovimiento"></div>
```

Botón para imprimir:

```
<a href="javascript:ImprimirMovimiento('ImprimirMovimiento')" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" title="Descargar movimiento"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>&nbsp;Descargar movimiento</a>
```

Comment: Hola. Esta respuesta esta usando Javascript para una pagina web. Mientras el codigo en la pregunta esta usando c# y parece no es una pagina web.